# WSO2 API manager publisher not support RTL language directon

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I going to change direction and also language of API manager publisher to Persian and RTL, but not working (it reads from default massages).Could you please guide me.

Comment: could you please elaborate about the question

Comment: Did you follow this doc?  https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/customizations/adding-internationalization/

Comment: how can I config publisher to RTL support ? it easily done in devportal, but in publisher I could't